# How to Set TD width Table on bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have Data table Jquery inside Bootstrap like This Picture
[image]

is look fine, but if I Resize the Browser(to see on mobile web) the picture is like this

[image]

Im so confuse, I try to set Widht manualy on table but not work.

And After I back to the Full Screen again(PC), the data table not center like this.

[image]

I have try add container but still not work. this Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Outbox</title>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../DT/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../DT/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../DT/responsive.bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kokola Email Template</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="email-setting.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="set.php">Set Header Footer</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="outbox.php">Outbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>




<?php

if(isset($_POST[HAPUS]))
{  
  include "../koneksi.php";

  $idhe = $_POST[ID];

  $jumlah = count($idhe);

 // echo $jumlah;

  for($i=0;$i<=$jumlah;$i++)
  {
      //echo $idhe[$i]."<br>";  

      $sql = "DELETE FROM outbox WHERE ID = '$idhe[$i]'";

      //echo $sql;

      //$hasil = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
      $hasil = mysql_query($sql);

  }//end for

  echo "<script>alert('Delete Berhasil dilakukan');</script>";



}

?>
<div class="center-block">
<form method="post" action="outbox.php">

<div style="margin-left:340px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;"><!--a-- href="email-setting.php"><img src="back.png"/></a-->
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="HAPUS" name="HAPUS" style="background-color:#F00;color:#FFF;border:0 none;
cursor:pointer;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;padding:5px 15px;margin-left:420px;" /></div>


 <!-- style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;" div style='overflow:auto;height:600px;width:700px;margin-left:300px;' style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:12px;"-->
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr height="100">
    <td colspan="5" align="center"><h2>Outbox</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
     <th align="center">Chek</th>
     <th align="center">Date Time</th>
     <th align="center">Tujuan</th>
     <th align="center">Subjek</th>
     <th align="center">Action</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <?php
 include "../koneksi.php";

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM outbox";

 //$hasil = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
 $hasil = mysql_query($sql);

 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
 { 

   echo "<tr height='50px'>";
     echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='ID[]' value='$data[ID]'></td>";
     echo "<td width='100' align='center'>$data[tglwkt]</td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>$data[tujuan]</td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>$data[subjek]</td>";
     echo "<td align='center'><a href='detail.php?ID=$data[ID]'><input type='button' value='Detail' style='background:#F00;color:#FFF;'></a></td>";

   echo "</tr>";

 }


 ?>
  </tbody>


</table>
<!--/div-->
</form>
   </div><!--center-blcok-->

</div><!--end container-->



<!--script-- src="../bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script-->
<script src="../DT/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="../DT/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script-->
<!--script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script-->
<script src="../DT/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../DT/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="../DT/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../DT/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can Anyone Help to Fix this. Im new on Bootstrap.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult without seeing your actual table code but getting a wide table like that looking good on mobile is tricky. Bootstrap has a [.responsive-table class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) that makes the table scroll horizontally on mobile.

Aside from that I'd see what styles on are being written to the table on mobile size, also try changing the td widths, that could be the culprit.

Also try removing classes like "dt-responsive" and "nowrap"

Answer (score 0):

Could your issue be that you haven't wrapped your table in a container, row and column DIV? Thus the width's aren't being dynamically set.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="example">
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**BTW.** If you could set up a jsFiddle it would help get a fast answer.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

If you are just trying to align the table in the center of the parent div, that can be accomplished with CSS.

```
#example {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have made a jsFiddle here as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DJRavine/cz1vpb1v/

Comment: It work, but after back to the pc, it still cant center. Anything Wrong?

Comment: Maybe the CSS was cached on your PC from before?
Try a hard refresh
IE / FF / CHROME: Hold down Ctrl and press F5.
SOURCE: https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/